# Changing theme in Apache Netbeans 9.0

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-9

I have installed [Apache Netbeans 9.0](http://netbeans.apache.org/community/index.html) recently in Mac running [macOS Mojave](https://www.apple.com/uk/macos/mojave/). I am trying to change the Netbeans theme to "**Dark Look And Feel Themes**" but I can't find the options.

Previously, I have used the older versions (8.2, 8.1, 8.0.2) of Netbeans. To change the theme, I navigate to

```
Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins
```

Install the "**Dark Look And Feel Themes**" plugin and restart the IDE to reflect the change.

But, I don't find this plugin in the Apache Netbeans 9.0

[image]

I also checked whether these plugins are available to download from online. So that I can add them using **'Downloaded'** option. But, they are only available for older versions.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/62424/darcula-laf-for-netbeans
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52624/netbeans-dark-theme

So, I am a bit stuck here. Any help will be much appreciated. There are few similar stack overflow questions raised earlier, but they all talk about the old version of Netbeans.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Updated 4/11/19:

Based on a comment from @superbiji below, Darcula + Norway Today works fine with **NetBeans 11.0**.

---

Updated 2/7/19:

*Note that the answer below applies only to **NetBeans 9.0**. The situation is a little different on **NetBeans 10.0** where the Dark Look and Feel plugin (themes "Dark Metal" and "Dark Nimbus") also worked fine. See [Projects, Files, Services, Navigator color background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54413349/2985643).*

---

I tried to download then manually install those two plugins on NetBeans 9.0, but it didn't work for me:

- Download the plugins as zip files, and unzip them.
- **Tools > Plugins >** click the **Downloaded** tab **>** click **Add Plugins...**
- The **Add Plugins** dialog opens, but it requires you to select a **jar** or **nbm** file, and no files of those types exist in the downloaded zip files.

However, there is an alternative approach that works for **Darcula** (but not for **Dark Look And Feel Themes**). It is a simple two step process:

1. Make the **Darcula** plugin available.
2. Automatically install the plugin, just as you would on NetBeans 8.2.

To make the plugin available:

- **Tools > Plugins > Settings** tab **>** Click the **Add** button.
- In the **Update Center Customizer** dialog that opens:

  - Enter some descriptive value in the **Name** field such as *NetBeans 8.2 plugins*
  - Enter http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/8.2/catalog.xml.gz in the URL field.
  - Click **OK** to make the plugins associated with that URL available for installation.

    [image: updateCustomizer]
- Now click the **Available Plugins** tab. You should see a lot of new entries, including one for **Darcula LAF for NetBeans**:

  [image: installDarcula]
- Check that entry and click **Install**, just as you would on NetBeans 8.2.

NetBeans 9.0 should restart using the **Darcula** theme:

[image: darculaInUse]

Notes:

- I don't think this approach is formally supported by NetBeans or the plugin author, but it works fine.
- To customize **Darcula** settings: **Tools > Options > Appearance >** click the **Darcula Look and Feel** tab.
- To switch from **Darcula** to one of the built in NetBeans look and feel options: **Tools > Options > Appearance >** click the **Look and Feel** tab > select an entry from the **Preferred look and feel** drop list.

Comment: As you mentioned, your solution is working for changing to 'Dracula' theme and not for 'Dark Look And Feel  theme'. It will be good if Apache Netbeans release the specific version for 9.0.

Comment: [1] I suspect that NetBeans just verify the plugin works, and then make it available, but it's up to the author of the plugin to ensure that it works on a given release. [2] I just managed to add the zip of '_Dark Look and Feel Theme_ using **Tools > Options > Import...**. It appeared successful, and NetBeans 9.0 restarted, but that theme was not visible following the restart.

Comment: @VimalDavid FYI, the _Dark Look And Feel_ themes (_Dark Metal_ and _Dark Nimbus_) are working fine with NetBeans 10.0 - see my answer to [Projects, Files, Services, Navigator color background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54413349/2985643)

Comment: Works for Netbeans 10 too

Comment: Thanks.... works for Netbeans 11 PHP , I use `Darcula` + `Norway Today`

Comment: @Superbiji Thanks for the information. I updated the answer based on your feedback.

Comment: Does not work on NetBeans 10.0. I get "There were some problems while storing Establishing a connection... Cause: Source URL for module "com.revivius.nb.darcula" is null"
Edit: I just tried it again and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you to check [NetBeans Themes](https://netbeansthemes.com/) website. It allows you to design and download your own themes.

[Twilight theme](https://netbeansthemes.com/twilight/) is a good example:
[image: Twilight]