# can i change appearence of the netbeans IDE 6.5.1

Tags: netbeans

i would like to change the netbeans IDE 6.5.1 from default white into dark theme ,unfortunately the are no plugins to my knowledge to change it into dark theme ,
have i missed out any other way ?and if there is a plugin  available for the same pls share .
thanking anybody who answers in advance.

Comment: I believe there is a plug-in.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52697694/8716187  why not upgrade Netbeans, it seems the plug-ins might have moved ahead of 8,9.

Comment: thank you .my school has asked me to use 6.5.1 coz the textbooks arent updated nd are based on 6.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can install a Plugin to do this for you, in your Netbeans toolbar navigate to :

```
Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins > search for Darcula LAF for Netbeans
```

Hope this can do the work for you .